# How to get float values instead of integers when polygonizing rasters using QGIS?

Tags: qgis, gdal, raster-conversion, polygonize

I'm using QGIS 3.16.13-Hannover to convert a TIF file (solar radiation grid cells) into a vector like a Geojson or Shapefile. I was confused that everytime I ran the polygonize workflow in QGIS, I was getting rounded up values, which was removing a lot of the nice resolution from my data.

I noticed that other people had complained about GDAL polygonize rounding values out [here](https://trac.osgeo.org/gdal/ticket/4516) and it seems like they added the --float parameter. But I try that in QGIS and I get errors.

[image]
[image]

Is it possible to use the Polygonize workflow and using the --float parameter in order to maintain float values (vs. rounding)

Answer (score 3):

Use the Processing toolbox -> Vector Creation -> [Raster Pixels to Polygons](https://docs.qgis.org/3.16/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectorcreation.html#raster-pixels-to-polygons) tool instead of the GDAL Polygonize tool.

Raster Pixels to Polygons converts floating point values.  You may need to dissolve afterwards, the tool converts pixels individually instead of grouping pixels of the same value into a single polygon.

[image]

Comment: I just cannot seem to find that in my menus or by searching the qgis docs. Same thing when I search youtube. Is this a plugin I need to install?

Comment: @Kyle Pennell, look in Processing Toolbox. Type 'raster pixels' into search bar.

Comment: ok, I think I got it...they really hide it well