# GDAL QGIS Polygonize function does not work properly

Tags: qgis, raster, gdal, raster-conversion

I have a single band raster, range in values from -0,19 to 0,34.
I am trying to convert it to a multipolygon shapefile, but I am only coming up with a single polygon, with only 0 or 1 values in its attribute table.

How do I proceed in order to make QGIS read my raster proporly?

Comment: Continuous (floating-point) values aren't particularly compatible with polygon conversion. If you have discrete real values, you should convert to integer first.

Comment: Any guides or suggestions on how to go about to doing this? I'm breaking the raster trying to convert it. thanks in advance

Comment: Use the Processing toolbox -> Vector Creation -> Raster Pixels to Polygons tool instead of the GDAL Polygonize tool. "Raster Pixels to Polygons" converts floating point values. https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/416010/2856